# I cannot print correctly character from MySQL with pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I use pyodbc to connect MySQL, and successful put some chinese data to MySQL but I can't print it out  for correct character

```
In[1]: import pyodbc
       cn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=localhost; PORT=3306;DATABASE=db; UID=root; PASSWORD=******;OPTION=3;CHARSET=UTF8;") 
       cn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
       cursor = cn.cursor()

In[2]: cursor.execute("insert into tc_lite values(2018, 05 ,06 ,0 ,0 ,'中文','測試',127, 110)")
       cursor.execute("select * from tc_lite;")
       cursor.fetchall()
out[2]: [(2018, 5, 6, 0, 0, '銝剜?', '皜祈岫', 127.0, 110.0)]
```

---

but when I use pymysql to connect, it can show the correct character

```
In[3]: conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',passwd='******',db="trydb", charset='utf8')
       cursor = conn.cursor()

In[4]: cursor.execute("select * from tc_lite;")
       cursor.fetchall()
out[4]: ((2018, 5, 6, 0, 0, '中文', '測試', 127.0, 110.0),)
```

If I want to use pyodbc, how can I fix it to show like pymysql's output

I work on win7, python 3.6.1, pyodbc 4.0.16, Jupyter Notebook 5.5.0

Comment: Your connection string shows that you are using the ANSI version of the MySQL ODBC driver. If you want to work with UTF-8 encoded text you should be using the UNICODE version of the driver.

Comment: Thanks you very much, Gord.  I put the connection string which I found on the internet, but didn't find out there are ANSI type and Unicode type. After change driver to Unicode I can print what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string shows that you are using the ANSI version of the MySQL ODBC driver. If you want to work with UTF-8 encoded text you should be using the UNICODE version of the driver.